# jQuery mobile and ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am using ajax to send a request where I save the id of the post in the url:

```
$.ajax({
    ...

    url: "/api/request?id=" + id,
    ...

});
```

From what I have read, jQuery mobile uses the url for to load "pages" and for history purposes. Is there any way to bypass this? I have googled but have not found something that works for me.

Thanks!

(It works fine without importing the jQuery mobile library)

**UPDATE**

```
 39 function getSavings(){
 40 
 41     id = window.location.hash.split("/")[1];
 42     console.debug(id);
 43 
 44     var cols = [];
 45     $("#history-table thead tr th").each(function(index, el){
 46         cols.push($(el).attr('data-col'));
 47     });
 48 
 49     $("#history-table tbody").html("")
 50     $("#history-table tbody").hide();
 51     $("#amount").hide();
 52     $.get({
 53             type: "GET",
 54             url: "api/savings?id=" + id,
 55             error: function(xhr, settings, exceptions){
 56                 alert("could not get item");
 57             },
 58             success: function(data){
 59                 $("#item-name").html(`${data.Savings.Name}`);
 60                 for(let r of data.Savings){
 61                     var amount = r.Amount;
 62                     r.Amount = formatSavings(amount);
 63                     $("#amount").html(`
 64                             <div>${r.Amount}<span class="sek">sek</span></div>
 65                     `).fadeIn();
 66 
 67                     $("#item-crumb").html(`
 68                             <div>${r.Name}</div>
 69                     `).fadeIn();
 70 
 71                 }
 72 
 73                 for(let r of data.History){
 74                     var date = new Date(r.Datee).toLocaleDateString();
 75                     var time = new Date(r.Datee).toLocaleTimeString();
 76                     r.Datee = `${date} <span class="badge">${time}</span>`;
 77                     var tr = `<tr>`;
 78                     for(let c of cols){
 79                         if(c === "Amount" || c === "UpdatedAmount"){
 80                             var amount = r[c];
 81                             r[c]= formatSavings(amount);
 82                         }
 83                         tr += `<td>${r[c]}</td>`
 84                     }
 85                     tr += `</tr>`
 86                     $("#history-table tbody").append(tr).fadeIn();
 87                 }
 88             }
 89     });
 90     $("#main-content").fadeIn();
 91 }
```

**error**
The error I get is: "404 not found"

Comment: You're doing everything right. From my experience with AJAX, the problem may be related to browser compatibility.Or some depreciation code in jquery .

Comment: @JoseMarques Unfortunately it don't work in any browser

Comment: I looked a bit more for the "error: 404 not found", and this is possible related to not finding the url. Your error is fetched from the console. If this is the case try to check the server-side error (server error log), for more information.